# PHP Session Variable Retrieval Slow

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a very odd problem, I'm trying get the value of a PHP session variable via an ajax call, and what has been working for months seems to not function quickly today.  After performing a search I am storing the number of results in a session variable called $_SESSION[adv_search][num_results].  Then I try to retrieve this session variable on a page by performing AJAX call:

```
//get number of results from last query
num_results = $.ajax({
  url: './ajax/getters/adv_search_num_results.php',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  async: false
}).responseText;//ajax
```

adv_search_num_results.php simply contains:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo($_SESSION[adv_search][num_results]);
?>
```

The AJAX call still works (relative term), but it takes so long now that chrome asks me to kill the page.  I need to use async: false because I need the num_results for other things such as pagination.

This used to function very quickly, and if I comment out that AJAX call and just assign a number to num_results, the searches are performed very quickly.  I'm not sure if anyone has the silver bullet, but any ideas would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified the db server and/or connection to it is not sluggish?

Comment: simshaun i don't think he is hitting the db in this particular instance, all he is doing is accessing a session variable.

Comment: The rest of the website functions fine, very quick response times.

Comment: it seems it has to do with locked session files. Try adding session_write_close() whenever you've done with the session

Comment: @Darhazer I added session_write_close(), but it doesn't seem to have any affect.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I can't think why it would happen, but there may be some clues at this page (plus a workaround)

http://forum.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=77977